# Multi-way KK differencing algorithm vs. Greedy algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, integer, heuristics

It's proven that, the *Karmarkar-Karp's differencing algorithm* always performs better than *greedy* for **2-way partitioning** problems, i.e. partitioning set of n integers to 2 subsets with equal sums. Can this be extended to **k-way partitioning** as well? If not, is there any example where greedy performs better than KK in k-way partitioning?

Comment: how do you want to apply differencing for three or more partition? !

Comment: @Lrrr KK heuristic can be applied k-way partitioning too. Giving the example from this paper: http://ijcai.org/papers09/Papers/IJCAI09-096.pdf

Let's say we want to partition (8,7,6,5,4) into 3 equal subsets. Here's the steps we're going to take:

- (8,0,0) (7,0,0) (6,0,0) (5,0,0) (4,0,0)
- (8,7,6) (5,0,0) (4,0,0)
- (5,0,0) (4,0,0) (2,1,0)*   --- * is the outcome of normalization
- (5,4,0) (2,1,0)
- (5,5,2) 
- (3,3,0)

So the difference between the final subsets is equal to 3 in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*KK's* superiority **cannot** be generalized for the k-way partitioning. In fact, it's easier to give a counter-example where the *Greedy algorithm* is performing better. 
Let the performance measure be the maximum subset sum of the final partition.
Now, take this set of integers:

S = [10 7 5 5 6 4 10 11 12 9 10 4 3 4 5] and k=4 (partitioning into 4 equal subsets)

Fast forward, *KK algorithm* gives the result of [28, 26, 26, 26] whereas the greedy gives the final partition of [27, 27, 27, 24]. Since 28 > 27, *greedy* performed better for this example.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with KK Algorithm solution provided.

- Sum(S) = 105
- Sum([28, 26, 26, 26]) = 106
- Sum([27, 27, 27, 24]) = 105

Greedy algorithm gives a result of

```
{{12, 6, 5, 4}{11, 7, 5, 4}{10, 10, 4, 3}{10, 9, 5}}
[27, 27, 27, 24]
```

KK algorithm gives a result of

```
{{5, 12, 6, 4}{5, 10, 7, 4}{5, 11, 10}{4, 3, 10, 9}}
[27, 26, 26, 26]
```

Since the highest sums are equal (27=27) and KK's lowest sum is greater than the Greedy Algorithm's (26>24), KK algorithm performs better. There are circumstances where Greedy Algorithm can still perform better than KK, but this example isn't one of them.